# Разворачивание html-таблицы по 10 строк по кнопке (не трогая html)

Tags: javascript, css, jquery

Требуется разворачивать большую html-таблицу по 10 строк при каждом нажатии кнопки "Показать еще 10".

Причем только средствами css/js, а html лучше не трогать.

Изначально в таблице должно быть развернуто 10 строк. А вся таблица может содержать до 200 строк. Из них 190 изначально свернуты. И разворачиваются по 10 строк при каждом нажатии на кнопку "Еще 10"

Видела такое где-то и когда-то. Не могу найти. 
Буду благодарна за пример, как это можно реализовать.
По возможности не очень сложный. Я в js совсем как ежик в тумане. А с jQuery разберусь.

Спасибо!

Comment: обычно в таком варианте данные получаются с сервера порциями...

Comment: На сервере нужная выборка берется из кэша. Полностью. Все данные по запросу, на каждую страницу свой запрос. Думаю, что брать только часть закэшированных данных по запросу не получится.

Comment: дело Ваше, сейчас сделаю пример

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
// эта строчка формирует html для примера
table.innerHTML = Array(200).fill(0).map((e, i) => 
    `<tr><td>a${i}</td><td>b${i}</td><td>c${i}</td></tr>`).join('')

// выберем все строки
let rows = document.querySelectorAll('table tr');
// скроем все строки после 10
rows.forEach((e, i) => e.style.display = i>10 ? 'none': 'block');
        
function more() {
  // счетчик 
  let count = 0;
  // перебираем все строки
  rows.forEach(el => {
    // если строка не видна и счетчик меньше 10
    if (el.style.display === 'none' && count < 10){
      // показываем строку
      el.style.display = 'block';
      // увеличиваем счетчик 
      count++;
    }
  })
}
```

```html
<table><tbody id="table"></tbody></table>
<button onclick="more()">more</button>
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо, Stranger! Это именно то, что мне  требуется!

Comment: @КвартирыПетербург уж извинете что не jQuery, хотя можно и им

Comment: Думаю, осилю. Азы я знаю. И развиваться люблю :))

Comment: @КвартирыПетербург да и сильно ничего не изменится